# SQL Foreign Key creating issue when inserting records

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

I have the following 2 tables:

**Table A**

```
AId INT NOT NULL
BId INT NOT NULL
```

**Table B**

```
BId INT NOT NULL
AId INT NOT NULL
```

`AId` of Table `A` is the primary key, and `BId` is a foreign key. Same thing is applied for `Table B`.

What I am trying to do is, I need to insert record in any table but both tables should get affected.

Is it possible or not, if possible then please suggest how?

Many thanks in advance...

Comment: You have a circular reference and what you have isn't going to work. What are you trying to do? (Meaning, what is the real problem you are trying to solve? This sounds very much like an XY problem.)

Comment: Actually I don't have any real problem. I just trying to accomplish this. That's why I asked is it possible or not :)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: @Ic. although I agree that circular references are not a good design choice, "*isn't going to work*" is wrong. You can very well insert rows into those tables when using deferred constraints (again: that is usually not a good idea)

Answer (score 1):

your telling about cross reference and it will not going to work

if you problem is automatically insert data into second table when insert happen to first table, use triggers

```
CREATE TRIGGER [TRIG_MyTable]
ON [MyTable]
AFTER INSERT
```

Comment: This is the way if you want automatic inserting except cross reference

Comment: nrsharma - what do you mean, it won't work? If you want to automatically update one table when you insert data into another table, it should work. If you want to link two tables together, then what is the purpose of this? You shouldn't have PK-FK and FK-PK relationships going both ways in a table - it's one or the other.

Comment: I don't want automatic insertion, my question was Can we insert data with this PK-FK and FK-PK, if yes then how?

Comment: According to meaning here "I need to insert record in any table but both tables should get affected"  it says when you insert one record to one table you want reflect that in second table, that's what says automatic insertion

Answer (score 0):

Use **deferred constraint** on foreign key.

Comment: I think this is for oracle only, is it possible in SQL?

Comment: @nrsharma: "*is it possible in SQL*" doesn't make sense. Oracle **does** use SQL as its query language. In fact **every** relational database uses SQL as its query language (and besides: Postgres, Derby and SQLite also support deferred constraints)

Comment: @nrsharma: As far as I know, deferred constraint supported database MSSQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL and possibly others. What do you use?

Comment: @AlexanderDrankin: I am using SQL SERVER 2005